# sslstrip not always working - only before successful login

Tags: ssl, packet-sniffers

I'm analysing an iOS app written with PhoneGap which first displays an HTTP-page. After tapping on "Login", the user is getting redirected to an HTTPS-page where she can enter the login information.

If I'm setting up arpspoof/sslstrip BEFORE the user logs in the first time, everythings fine. Wireshark confirms that the login data is submitted to an HTTP-Page, so sslstrip did its job.

But if the user logged e.g. one hour BEFORE I could set up arpspoof/sslstrip, the second request (= the login) is sent via HTTPS, even if the app was completely closed. Only if I set the iPads date far in the future, it works again. Then, irritatingly, it also works if I set the date to the current time.

If the app is deleted and installed new, everything works again as expected. What's happening if the user logged in before? Why can't sslstrip do its job then?

My setup:
Kali Linux with the following command:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -t nat --flush
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -i PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8008
arpspoof -i wlan0 -t SMARTPHONE-IP GATEWAY-IP
```

as well as

```
#!/bin/bash
sslstrip -k -f -l 8008 --write=sslstrip.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the application is caching some information. And if you access the original page with the https link/form inside before sslstrip is active it will be cached and later used with https references still intact.
By fiddling with the date of the system you reach the expiration time for the cached page, so that it will ignore the cached entry and request the page again, this time through sslstrip. Also, if you delete the app the cache will be deleted too, so that after reinstalling it needs to retrieve the page again.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this? Do you have an idea how I could force re-fetching the page without physical access to the iOS-Device?

Comment: It depends on the application. If it just uses the cached page w/o checking for a newer one you have no chance, because there is nothing you could intercept. But, if the application checks if there is a newer version by requesting the page with If-Modified-Since or If header you could strip the headers from the request so that the server gives the full page. But giving that fiddling with the clock solves the problem I guess that it just uses the cached page w/o checking for a new one.

Comment: You might also try to deny the direct SSL query. Some applications will then try to refetch the starting page using non-encrypted HTTP.

Comment: I'll give it a try in Monday, thanks a lot! What irritates me is the fact that I always have to use different times in the future; once, two hours were sufficient, now I mostly have to use dates in 2015... I'll get back to this in Monday!

Comment: I just found a HSTS-header set to one year, which seems to explain the behaviour. Furthermore, I think there's no chance avoiding this... do you know further information about this? I mean - where or how is it stored, does it survive reboots etc.?

Comment: I would guess it will survive reboots. If you have access to the device I would suggest du do SSL man-in-the-middle instead of ssltrip, e.g. using mitmproxy, fiddler or similar stuff and add your own mitm-CA to the device.

Comment: I do NOT have physical access to the device when proofing the security leak to the customer, I only have access during analyzing what's happening. I would say it doesn't matter if it doesn't work every time, I just need to understand it better, i.e. how and where this information is stored (inside the app or globally on the iOS device) and if it survives reinstalling the app, reboots, deleting the cache etc.

Comment: You might even be able to do an MITM attack w/o installing your own MITM-CA. There are lots of applications out there which don't do proper certificate checks.

Comment: unfortunately, iOS does the check - I tried MITM with Charles-Proxy: Kali is used to redirect the traffic through my Mac running Charles, but as soon as I try to navigate from HTTP to HTTPS in my app, I see that the request is blocked as the certificate is invalid. So Phonegap/Safari seems to do the job of checking if the certificate is valid. I guess it's no different with tools like mitmproxy or fiddler?